# Docker agent in jenkins is offline

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm facing an issue with my Jenkins setup, and I hope someone can help me troubleshoot and resolve it.

I have a Docker agent configured in Jenkins, and it was working fine until recently. However, now the Docker agent is offline, and I see the following error message in the system log:
An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out: No data received within 60000ms. Perhaps the docker API (tcp://10.0.8.6:4243) is not responding normally, or perhaps you need to increase the readTimeout value.

Additionally, when I check the status of the Docker daemon on the host machine, I get the following error:

error msg="failed to load container"
error msg="failed to load container mount

I've tried to diagnose and resolve the issue, tried restarting docker service and jenkins  but I'm not sure how to resolve.
Could someone please guide me on how to troubleshoot this issue? What steps should I take to investigate and resolve this Docker agent offline problem and the Docker daemon error?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).